# Call a function when CSS is class added / removed

Tags: javascript, css

Preamble - absolutely [no jQuery](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335328/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question)!

I need to monitor a particular DOM element that I have access to via:

```
var element = document.getElementById('the-element');
```

When a CSS class is added or removed from `element`, I need the CSS class name to be delivered to a function.

I am happy to accept reasonable workarounds.

For example:

```
element.onClassChange(myFunction);

function myFunction(classname, state) {
    console.log('The classname is '+classname+' - '+state);
}
```

Comment: Is this a challenge? or you have problem?

Comment: you can add class using setAttribute("class", "yourclass")

Comment: Have a look at [MutationObserver](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-mutationobserver) and check in the callback, if a class was changed.

Comment: Ignore the accepted answer (jQuery) and instead have a look at the highest voted answer

Comment: @Andreas Wonderful, I missed that!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id = "classToAdd" classAdded=false>Click the button to trigger a function that will output "Hello World" in a p element with id="demo".</p>

<button onclick="addClassToP()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function addClassToP() {

 var pEle = document.getElementById("classToAdd");

 pEle.className += "addedClassName"; 
 pEle.classAdded = true;

 pEle.onchange();
}

document.getElementById("classToAdd").onchange = function(){
  if(this.classAdded){
     alert("class added");
     // do something on class added
     this.classAdded = false; // restoring the classAdded notifier attribute
  }
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry about the first answer, I updated the answer in core js :) . I added an attribute classAdded which will determine whether the class is added or not. I added alert code on onchange event. Whenever I add class to the p tag, I set the classAdded attribute to true and then call the onchange() manually.    You have to set classAdded to true and call onchange() while adding any class.